# Error while starting 9th Virtual machine installed on XEN

Tags: virtualization, xen, xenserver

I have a blade server of HP proliant with 64 Gb of RAM and 1TB hard-disk. I installed Cent OS 5.6 with XEN enabled on it.

I used **xenbr0**(xenbridge) mode and not virbr0 mode for configuring my networking in XEN.

I was successful in installing virtual machines on it and cloning them. I started 8 of these VMs and everything worked fine, but when I started 9th VM (excluding Dom-0) following error came.

**"Error starting domain : post operation failed:xend_post:error from xen daemon:(xend.err) 'Device 768(vbd) could not be connected. Failed to find an unused loop device"**

I tried searching for the solution and found that I need to increase "options netloop nloopbacks". I did it in /etc/modprob.d file and rebooted the system but it didn't work either.

I didn't understand it but am I doing something wrong here. I target to install **100 VM**s on this machine as I have enough hardware resources. Is it possible? and if yes how can I solve above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create more loopback devices (`/dev/loopX` where X is 0-7). By default there is 8

If you have loopback compiled into the kernel (which most people do) you can add this to the kernel line in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`

`max_loop=128`

Then reboot

Also, you can try editing `/etc/modprobe.conf` and adding

`options loop max_loop=128`